# IRB: exit a changed binding (`cb`) without exiting entire IRB session?

Tags: ruby, binding, irb

In an IRB session, I can use `cb` (change binding) to enter an object, but how do I get out? If I use `exit` it exits the entire IRB session.

```
$ irb
❯ o = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x007fc8a32258a8>
❯ cb(o)
=> #<Object:0x007fc8a32258a8>
❯ self
=> #<Object:0x007fc8a32258a8>
❯ exit
$
```

For that matter, how do I continue navigating objects once I've started? I've found I can access the `cb` method from whichever object I'm in by first extending `IRB::ExtendCommandBundle`, but is there a less tedious way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be to use pry instead. It's a very powerful debugger that can also be used for most of the things irb is used for. I use it for inspecting my code and objects in rails apps.

https://github.com/pry/pry

Get it with `gem install pry`

Then you can do this:

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> cd ""
[2] pry(""):1> self
=> ""
[3] pry(""):1> exit
=> ""
[4] pry(main)> exit
$
```

Along with much, much more.

Comment: Yes! I had a vague memory of using a `cd` in addition to `cb`. Must have been Pry I was thinking of.